# How do you take a variable from a function that takes an input from an html form and use it in another function

Tags: javascript, html

here i am taking a input from a drop down form on a html page. And i am putting it in to a var called AM.

```
 var e = document.getElementById("UserTimeAM");
    function onChangeAM() {
      var AM = e.value;
      var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
      console.log(AM, text);
    }
    e.onchangeAM = onChangeAM;
    onChangeAM();
```

From there a fetch is called to an api and i am using the AM variable in it. But the issue is that when the site is being served it comes back with an error saying AM is not defined.

```
lowHigh.forEach(d =>{
    let wDate = new Date(d.time).getUTCDate();
    let AM_Hour = AM;
    let PM_Hour = PM;
    AM_Hour = ("0" + AM_Hour);

    if(wDate == i+1)
        {
            if(tidedata1.innerHTML == "")
            {
                
                tidedata1.innerHTML = `${AM_Hour}: - ${d.value}m`
                tidedata1Full.innerHTML = `${AM_Hour}:am - ${d.value}m`
            }
            else
            {
                tidedata2.innerHTML = `${PM_Hour}: - ${d.value}m`
                tidedata2Full.innerHTML = `${PM_Hour}:pm - ${d.value}m`
            }
        }
    })
```

I thought using var would mean it was a global so the variable could be passed in to different functions.

Comment: Using var most definitely doesn't bypass scope. Try it yourself! `function a() { var b = 1; } console.log(b);` <-- `ReferenceError: 'b' is not defined`.

Comment: What @code said is true, but plz be cautious, please check my answer to understand the problem.

Comment: Any questions, please comment so I can edit my answer, I wish you success on your journey :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize the `AM` variable in the scope outside of your two functions to make it possible to use it in both

```
var AM;
var e = document.getElementById("UserTimeAM");
    function onChangeAM() {
      AM = e.value;
      var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
      console.log(AM, text);
    }
    e.onchangeAM = onChangeAM;
    onChangeAM();

lowHigh.forEach(d =>{
    let wDate = new Date(d.time).getUTCDate();
    let AM_Hour = AM;
    let PM_Hour = PM;
    AM_Hour = ("0" + AM_Hour);

    if(wDate == i+1)
        {
            if(tidedata1.innerHTML == "")
            {
                
                tidedata1.innerHTML = `${AM_Hour}: - ${d.value}m`
                tidedata1Full.innerHTML = `${AM_Hour}:am - ${d.value}m`
            }
            else
            {
                tidedata2.innerHTML = `${PM_Hour}: - ${d.value}m`
                tidedata2Full.innerHTML = `${PM_Hour}:pm - ${d.value}m`
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank for that. But could you also put the `var AM = e.value` outside but under the function? or is that bad practice?

Comment: You can't put it outside because you want it to run every time there is a change of the value

Comment: @mciver9010 If my answer solved your problem, I would appreciate it if you marked it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

---

In order to fully understand the differences between each of the identifiers (let, var, const) we first need to understand the concept of scope.

What is Scope?
Scope determines the accessibility or visibility of variables to JavaScript. There are three types of scope in JavaScript:

1. Global scope
2. Function (local) scope
3. Block scope (new with ES6)

- Global Scope
Variables declared **outside a function** are in the **global scope**. 
Global variables can be accessed and changed in any other scope.

- Local Scope
Variables defined **within a function** are in **local scope** and are not accessible in other functions.

Each function, when invoked, creates a new scope, therefore variables with the same name can be used in different functions.

Reference: [JavaScript: Var, Let, or Const? Which One Should you Use?](https://codeburst.io/javascript-var-let-or-const-which-one-should-you-use-2fd521b050fa)

#### Example

---

```
var first = 123;

if(true) {
  var second = 456;
}

function abc(){
  var third = 789;
}

abc();
```

Note that `first` and `second` are inside global scope, and `third` is in function (local) scope, because its declared inside a function

#### Important note

---

Variables declared using the var keyword are either globally or functionally scoped, they do not support block-level scope. This means that if a variable is defined in a loop or in an if statement it can be accessed outside the block and accidentally redefined leading to a buggy program. As a general rule, you should avoid using the var keyword.

Example:

```js
function DoSomething(){
  if(true){ //Some condition [only example]
     var example = 123;
  }

  console.log({example})
}
DoSomething()
```

If it had been declared as a let, it would not be visible, and would belong to the ({}) block of the if, example:

```js
function DoSomething(){
  if(true){ //Some condition [only example]
     let example = 123;
  }

  console.log({example})
}
DoSomething()
```

In this example above, i'm using `let`, with will generate an error, that is a good thing to alert the programmer.

#### How to solve

---

Just as @HaimAbeles said, you just need to initialize the AM variable in the scope outside of your two functions to make it possible to use it in both

Example:

```
var AM;
var e = document.getElementById("UserTimeAM");
    function onChangeAM() {
      AM = e.value;
      var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
      console.log(AM, text);
    }
    e.onchangeAM = onChangeAM;
    onChangeAM();
...
```